# Subtract from a integer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtract from an integer using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354458/subtract-from-an-integer-using-jquery)

I want to subtract 50 from the offset of a div.
My code is this.

```
if (scroll) {
    $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop":  $(scroll).offset().top - 50});
        $(scroll).css('color', 'blue');
        $(scroll).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
        });
    }
```

But this isn't working. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Subtract and do *what*? Define "isn't working"

Comment: Are you referring to margin top?

Comment: @AnoopssGolden :- yes margin-top

Comment: You haven't set it to anything; you are simply subtracting 50 from a number and letting the value drop off into space. Both of the answers below so far show you how you can *assign* that value to something, so it will "do" something.

Comment: What is in the variable scroll? What is it you are checking for in if (scroll) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `css` method to change the `top` property

```
$('div').css('top', $('div').offset().top - 50);​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WYuTm/1/).

**Update:**

```
$('div').animate({'top' : $('div').offset().top - 50});
```

Also make sure `if (scroll)` evaluates true.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WYuTm/10/).

Comment: Since offset().top not equals to the 'top' in css this will only work is the DOM is this easy. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/WYuTm/2/ to see when it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css` method

```
$('div').CSS('margin-top','-50');
```