# Subtract from an integer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to a div each time user presses **j** key. Here is the code for it.

```
$(function() {
    function scroll(direction) {

        var scroll, i,
                positions = [],
                here = $(window).scrollTop(),
                collection = $('.message_box');

        collection.each(function() {
            positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],0));
        });

        for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
            if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
        }

        if (scroll) {
        $('html, body').animate({"scrollTop": $(scroll).offset().top-50});
            $(scroll).css('color', 'blue');
            $(scroll).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
            });
        }

        return false;
    }

    $("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
    });
$('body').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 74) {
     return scroll('next');
   }
});
$('body').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 75) {
     return scroll('prev');
   }
});

});
```

I need to subtract 50 from the offest of the div to scroll to which is this.

```
$('html, body').animate({"scrollTop": $(scroll).offset().top-50});
```

It will scroll the first time but not the rest of the times. I always  get the integer **218** which is the offset of the first div to scroll to.
DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/XP5sP/6/
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "it isn't working"? Exactly what is happening that isn't what you want/expect, and what is it that you do want/expect?

Comment: Also, any chance of a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist http://jsfiddle.net/XP5sP/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're always moving the `scrollTop` value to 50 pixels **before** the first matched element, so it's always identifying that element as the one you need to scroll to in your `if` statement because its position **is** greater than the current `scrollTop` value.

Modify the relevant section of your code to this:

```
if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here + 50) {
    scroll = collection.get(i);
    break;
}
```

That way it accounts for the window being scrolled to 50 pixels above the current element.

Answer (score 1):

`$(scroll).offset().top-50` is prefectly valid, as `.top` will return an integer value. Therefore the issue is not with this portion of your code.

I suspect the issue is to do with the `scroll` variable you have within the `scroll` function. I always keep away from naming my variables the same as my function names when within the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some space between your minus symbol so it does not get mistaken for a dash.

```js
$('html, body').animate({"scrollTop": $(scroll).offset().top - 50});
```

or save your mathematics in a variable first

```js
var scrollMinusFifty = $(scroll).offset().top - 50;
$('html, body').animate({"scrollTop":scrollMinusFifty});
```